# How to get joint position(x,y,z) of a robotic arm

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, joint, urdf, position

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that I can get joint angles of each joint from /joint_state topic of a urdf robotics arm. How to get a joint position(x,y,z) of each joint.Whether there is any other topic publishing it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257333/how-to-get-joint-position(x,y,z)--of-a-robotic-arm/) by [anadgopi1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/28124/anadgopi1994/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2017-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question was asked several times in the last weeks (especially by http://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) so please first use the search function. You can find solutions in [q255597](http://answers.ros.org/question/255597/how-get-posexyz-of-links-and-plot-in-rqt/)

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-03-19**:
and [q252572](http://answers.ros.org/question/252572/how-to-plot-positionx-y-z-and-velocity-of-fixed-framesend-effector-in-rqt/)